# Always gives me null when I try to deserialize a json string with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Help me with my problem i try get data from web API for method post, but always show null.

```
    public class ShippingQuantity
    {
      public string QuantityLoad { get; set; }
      public string QuantityLoaded { get; set; }
      public string QuantityPendingLoad { get; set; }
      public string ElementInfo { get; set; }
      public Guid kElement { get; set; }
      public string LineNumber { get; set; }
   }


   public class ShippingQuantityData
   {
      public List<ShippingQuantity> shippingData { get; set; }
      public string message { get; set; }
   }
```

and it its my code

```
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
         {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync(urlService, formContent);
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               var Response = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShippingQuantityData>(Response);
            }
```

when execute for mode debug the variable Response show it

```
 "{
  \"data\": [
    {
      \"QuantityLoad\": \"5\",
      \"QuantityLoaded\": \"1\",
      \"QuantityPendingLoad\": \"4\",
      \"ElementInfo\": \"2147-PIZZA 6 UNIDADES\",
      \"kElement\": \"8fa2ec91-2b20-415c-a65d-11c13d6725fd\",
      \"LineNumber\": \"1\"
    }
  ],
  \"Message\": \"\"
}"
```

thanks

Comment: Is it a typo that your class is called `ShippingQuantity` and you're deserializing `ShippingQuantityData`?

Comment: excuse me forget to place the other class, i update answer

Comment: Well, your JSON has a property named `data` and one called `Message`, and your class has one called `shippingData` and one called `message`. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is `List<T>` and you tried to deserialize the list to an object, try deserialize to `List<T>`.

Comment: But ShippingQuantityData is a single object which contains a List<ShippingQuantity> and a string property (Message). So I think that won't be any problem with the serialization.

Comment: I already mean this.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, my problem was resolve , set this decorator to all propertys and ii working [JsonProperty("NamePropertyObjectJson")]